# How to know NIC firmware in Solaris 11.3?

Tags: solaris, network-interface, firmware

I have Oracle Solaris 11.3 (Intel) installed. In my server, I have three different NIC adapters placed. I have recently upgraded the firmware.

I want to know whether the firmware has been successfully upgraded and reflected in OS or not. How can I know the firmware version of NIC adapters in Solaris 11.3?

Comment: Intel or sparc?

Comment: Intel. Sorry, I forgot to mention.

Comment: Some drivers log information to `/var/adm/messages` on boot.  Have you looked there?

Answer (score 2):

According to the manual you might be able to see the firmware level using:

```
dladm show-link -p fw-vers
```

See `man dladm` for additional details.

Update:

Apparently the command should be `dladm show-linkprop -p fw-vers`. Sample output from a Dell server running Solaris 11.3:

```
root@myhost:~# dladm show-linkprop -p fw-vers
LINK     PROPERTY        PERM VALUE        EFFECTIVE    DEFAULT   POSSIBLE
net1     fw-vers         r-   5.0.1.5      5.0.1.5      --        -- 
net0     fw-vers         r-   5.0.1.5      5.0.1.5      --        --
```

Comment: Can you please provide few examples as this is not working in my case.

Comment: Hi @Amit24x7, I updated the answer, can you please review?

Comment: I tried the above command but last four columns are empty in my case. I'm running Solaris 11.3 on HPE servers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `modinfo <nic_module>` ?

From the venerable Solaris docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19407-01/820-7898-11/z40001c91006813.html

EDIT:

Are you sure the driver version is not bumped when you install new firmware ?

List all pkg's that are related to ethernet drivers

```
# pkginfo | grep -i ethernet
```

Pick the one that matches your nic(s)

```
# pkginfo -x SUNWced
SUNWced  Sun GigaSwift Ethernet Adapter Driver
     (sparc.sun4v) 1.0,REV=2005.08.30.10.0
```

From https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.000021363

If you could tell us which nics you have we could probably help more.

Comment: This will show the driver version but not the firmware. Apart from this, even I don't know few modules name. If you can help me with that also, that would be grateful.

Comment: I have HPE 331FLR, HPE 530SFP+, and HPE NC365T NIC adapters. The drivers' name I have got by `dladm show-phys` command but still, I'm not getting the firmware version.